# create a matrix with random values based on a normal distrubition

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

Let take the following data:

```
Mini <- c(8500, 11000,  10500,  12000,  9500,   10500, 12000, 11500)
Kleinwagen <- c(8500,  10500,   10500,  10500,  12500,  12000,  13000,  13500)
Kompatklass <- c(11000, 13000,  12500,  13000,  13500,  15500,  15500,  17500)
minivans <- c(6000, 11500,  10500,  13000,  13000,  14000,  14500,  19000)
sportswagen <- c(12000,  12000, 14000,  18000,  16000,  17000,  26000,  21500)
utilities <- c(7500, 11000, 11500,  11000,  12000,  16500,  16500,  21500)
mittleklass <- c(11000, 12000,  14000,  14000,  15000,  17500,  28000, 26000)
oberemittle <- c(11000,  13500, 14000,  14500,  17000,  20000,  25000, 30500)
bigvans <- c(13000,  12500, 16000,  15000,  16000,  17000,  18500, 37500)

Dist.table <- t(data.frame(Mini, Kleinwagen, Kompatklass, minivans, sportswagen, utilities, mittleklass, oberemittle, bigvans))
```

Now I assume each value is the mean. I also assume a constant standard deviation of 0.7%

If I use:

```
b <- rnorm(1, mean = Dist.table[1, 1], sd = Dist.table[1, 1] * 0.007)
```

I generate a random number for [1,1].

But I want to create a full matrix of random variables

Comment: You set the amount of numbers to generate to `1` (it is the first argument of `rnorm` function) of course it generates only one values. Another point I do not get: why you create a matrix and the want to fill with the random numbers? why you just don't `matrix(rnorm(80, sd = 0.7), ncol = 8)` ?

Comment: the 1 is used as a guide, eventfully i want to introduce permutations to create a series of matrix's

Comment: If what you're trying to do is add noise to each of the values in `Dist.table`, you could always just do `Dist.table + matrix(rnorm(80, sd=0.7), ncol=8)`.

Comment: @ Josh, this generates an error. Also you are introducing noise by setting a mean of 80. Each number in my matrix already is a mean

Comment: If you want to work with a standard deviation of `0.7%`, you will need to multiply with `0.007` (else you imply a SD of 70%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
matrix(rnorm(prod(dim(Dist.table)), mean = Dist.table, sd = Dist.table * 0.007), nrow = nrow(Dist.table))
```